# NPM PROBLEM: Node-pre-gyp. Using request for node-pre-gyp https download

Tags: node.js, express, npm, sqlite

I am creating Angular project and using Express.js as back-end and SQLite3 for database. When I am installing sqlite3 via command `npm install sqlite3` I'm getting following error in the console. How can I solve this problem?

```
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
```

[image: Error is at the bottom with purple color]

Answer (score 14):

It's a warning saying that it needs to download prebuilt binaries to install the module.

`sqlite3` is a native module, so it either needs to be built from source or installed via binary download. If you have Visual Studio installed, you ca try `npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source`, which is also a safer option.

Comment: If you face the same issue using another package. just add `--build-from-source` to your command :)